# Can "non-native" pointers hurt cache performance?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, prefetch, cpu-cache

As far as I can tell, hardware prefetchers will at the very least detect and fetch constant strides through memory. Additionally it can [monitor data access patterns](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/08/24/what-you-need-to-know-about-prefetching), whatever that really means. Which led me to wonder, **do hardware prefetchers ever base their decisions on actual data stored in memory, or purely based on the behaviour a program is exhibiting?**

The reason I ask is because I will occasionally use "non-native" pointers as pointers. A simple example of this would be a preallocated array of stuff, and small integers indexing this array instead of pointers. If I need to store a whole lot of such "pointers", the savings in memory can add up quickly and in turn indirectly improve cache-performance by using less memory.

But for all I know, this might interfere with how hardware prefetchers work. Or not!

I can certainly imagine, realistic or not, a prefetching unit that examines cache lines that enters L1 cache for native pointer addresses and starts fetching them into L2 or some such thing. In that case, my clever trick of saving memory suddenly seems less decidedly clever.

**So, what do modern hardware prefetchers do, really? Can they be tripped up by "non-native" pointers?**

Comment: I might sound stupid but what is a non-native pointer?

Comment: In this question, a "native" pointer is supposed to be a value that holds a memory address in a literal sense. `0x1234` would point to the memory at `0x1234`. A "non-native" pointer would be a value that refers to memory in an indirect way. `0x1234` in this context may refer to memory at `some_array[0x1234]`, or something more complex like `array = some_map[0x1234>>8]; pointer = array[0x1234&0xff]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Linked data structures (LDS) prefetching is still a known problem in computer architecture. I'm not familiar with any modern CPU that actually does that, but in theory it's possible. There have been several academy papers over the years that propose some variations over:

1. A dedicated HW that can detect address-like values within fetched cache lines, and issue prefetches to these addresses.
2. A compiler-assisted technique where the compiler recognized the data structure dependencies and inserts SW prefetches or other hints.

Both these methods may be affected by your technique (the first would be rendered useless, the second may work if the compiler is sufficiently clever).

Of course you'd have to actually run on such a machine so it's only theoretical, and you shouldn't have to change your practice if it works fine for you, but it goes to show that profiling should be specific per micro-architecture and system, and what helps you in one case, may be less efficient on another.
Generally speaking - don't just trust the CPU to do or not do some optimization (unless it's documented), always check you get the expected behavior.

By the way, note that even if the HW sees the content of the memory, it's still in the virtual address space - the HW would anyway have to do some sort of translation to physical address to use it, so in a sense there doesn't have to be any additional overhead.

Some bibliography:

- [Compiler-Directed Content-Aware Prefetching for Dynamic Data Structures](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1238005&tag=1)
- [Dependence Based Prefetching for Linked Data Structures](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=291034)
- [Guided Region Prefetching: A Cooperative Hardware/Software Approach](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=859663)

Comment: Accepting this as it most directly answers the question at hand: No, there are currently no known CPU that does prefetching based on linked data.

Comment: Well, if I ever finish my thesis i'll see if I can sell it to Intel/AMD/.. , and maybe there will be one someday :)

Answer (score 21):

The hardware prefetcher doesn't see pointers, it sees memory addresses. It doesn't care where the address came from, or what type it had in the C++ program you wrote. It just looks at which address the CPU is being told to read to or write from.

So no, indexing into an array is not going to be a scary new thing that the CPU has never encountered before.

Comment: Exactly. Don't think in terms of *types* when trying to understand a CPU's capabilities.

Comment: That's not entirely accurate, a theoretical future CPU may decide to prefetch ahead based on data, such techniques were proposed in the academy

Comment: @MarcClaesen: well, to be fair to the OP, even in terms of CPU representation there is a difference between how a memory address is represented (8 bytes on 64bits) and how an offset from "known" address is represented (maybe only 2 bytes, if it suffices). The proposed "new-fangled" optimization of prefetching memory at whatever looks like a memory address in the L1 cache seems perfectly legitimate, for example, and would be crushed by the "memory savings" offset.

Comment: @jalf: Of course it doesn't see types. But does see memory addresses? **When** does it "see" a memory address? When it is put into a register? When it is actually used *as* a memory address?

Comment: @Leeor: That was a theory in the past. Current consensus is to use an explicit prefetch instruction for those cases. Other fetches can be handled fairly efficiently in the pipeline.

Comment: @Marc: I am not talking about *types* as they exist in a language. But a 16-bit index into an array is something very different from a 64-bit value referring to a "native" memory location.

Comment: @MSalters, it's been first proposed long ago, but the idea is far from being dead. SW prefetches can't help you run ahead a linked data-structure since you still don't know the address. Pipelining also doesn't help in such cases as the fetches are dependent. In general, it's still an open problem.

Comment: @Leeor: That's a rather fundamental limitation: you have to read N random addresses to get the Nth node. The pipeline already can note that you're doing a read into R1 using the address currently stored in R1. That means it can schedule that fetch to happen as soon as the address is resolved. This is still a fairly normal fetch for modern CPU pipelines, and yet it's as fast as any kind of data-dependent prefetch could be.

Comment: @MSalters - Data dependent prefetches can be implemented on lower cache levels, even in the memory controller (and "guess" the physical translation or work within page boundaries) - that's way faster then going all the way up to the Mem unit and issuing the next fetch. Anyway, this is beside the point - i'm arguing that assuming that no CPU will ever do this is a bit risky, that's all.